# Setting UTC as time zone in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I'm working on an application and I ran into a little problem...

How do I work with time zones and will there be conflicts between PHP and MySQL? What I was thinking of doing is setting the time zone to UTC in PHP like this `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` and storing it in MySQL using DATETIME.

Will MySQL change the time I provide via PHP to whatever time zone it has set or will it just store the value provided? If it will change it, how can I set the time zone in MySQL to UTC as well.

I would like to set the time zone to UTC so if I ever do need to worry about changing time for different time zones, I can just add/subtract whatever the offset is.

P.S. I'm new to web development.

Comment: Whatever your timezone is in MySQL or PHP, timestamp should be the same value. I personally think that storing timestamps in database is the best practice. You can later use these values and format output date/time as you wish (ex. to show different output to different timezone users, different date/time formats, etc.)

Comment: But if I wanted to use DATETIME in MySQL, would there be any problems doing it the way I mentioned just setting the time zone in PHP, getting the current time using date() and inserting into MySQL... Or would MySQL change the value to whatever its time zone is?

Comment: Well m8, guess I'm just not the right person to answer this question. Generally, I always keep timestamp in database and timezone of database or php don't matter much (timestamp is same moment of time anywhere). Later while extracting data, I use date() to format timestamp into date-time string according to what users set as their timezone. Keeping timestamps also allow me to easily deal with date-time ranges which is all I need at and I work with at the moment. Actually, never used DATETIME in MySQL and can't tell more about it because I store in database what returned with PHP's time() func.

Comment: Course, I use this approach which doesn't mean it's the best but still fits my personal requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to extract TimeZone Offset value. Then add it to your actual date time value. It will convert your Date Time value to UTC time.

```
set @TimeZoneOffSet := TIMEDIFF(NOW(),UTC_TIMESTAMP);
select ADDTIME(date_time_column,@TimeZoneOffSet) from table_name;;
```